# Call a sub-component method from parent compoent in Angular 2 +

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, and as the title states, I'm trying to see if this is doable.

Instead of using the standard way of a sub-component sending data via it's `@Output EventEmitter`, I would like to have the same concept (without injecting the parent into the child) but with the parent component emitting data to a child. Can a parent component emit data to a child? If not, why is that so?

Just to clarify, the sub-component is a form that gets filled in. As soon as the form is complete I want a button on the parent component to see if the form was complete before submitting it.

Comment: I think you may google it now..

Comment: If you know about `@Output()` so you must be knowing, there is `@Input()` also.

Comment: I think I did just that. I wouldn't be using SO if google searches gave me a definitive answer. So if you have an answer to the question specifically, please provide one @AkhilAravind

Comment: Or you can use a service to share data between components [Angular services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

Comment: Try to Use a Service, where you can handle the Form. You can use this service in other Components also.

Answer (score 3):

This was achieved simply by [interacting](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable) with the child component using a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars).

Add the variable to the child component selector element and access its properties and methods with it from the parent template:

```
<child-selector #variable ></child-selector>
<button (click)="variable.ChildMethod()"/>
```

Alternatively, access the child component method/properties directly from component class:

```
<button (click)="AccessChildMemebers(variable)"/>
AccessChildMemebers(elem){
    elem.ChildMethod();
}
```